# Find the last row of a $3 \times 3$ matrix given the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was able to get the last row of $A$ by replacing the asterisks with $x$ and $y$, doing $(0- \lambda)(x- \lambda)-(x)=0$ and plugging in $4$ and $7$ for $\lambda$. I got $x=-28$ and $y=11$.

However, I tried to do the same for matrix C and could not get the values for the last row. My work resulted in $(z-1)=(4z-8)=(9z-27)$, which doesn't give a consistent value for $z$. Even if I got $z$ from this work, I still don't know how I would get $x$ and $y$.

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

$$ C - \lambda I = \left[\begin{matrix} -\lambda & 1 & 0 \\  0& -\lambda& 1 \\ x & y & z - \lambda \end{matrix}\right]  $$

So that

$$ \det(C - \lambda I)  = \lambda^2(z-\lambda)+x+\lambda y $$

Using the given eigenvalues this leads to the system of equations

\begin{align}
(z-1)+ x+y &= 0 \\[2ex]
4(z-2)+ x+2 y &= 0 \\[2ex]
9(z-3)+ x+3 y &= 0 \\[2ex]
\end{align}

which leads to the solution $x=6$, $y=-11$, and $z=6$.